# Assemble custom Apache Sling instance

Tags: apache, osgi, sling

I am playing around with Apache Sling for a while now. Usually i download the self runnable jar and start it up. Then I deploy my projects to that sling instance.
Till now I never really thought about assembling my own Apache Sling instance. But at last years adaptTo conference i heard about the new "Sling Feature Model". When I saw the presentation, I didn't really get the benefits. 
But now I am interested on how to use it. Does anyone know a guide/documentation, that could help me getting started?